# send nested $http request in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS ***1.6.4*** application in need to some check before send any $http request so I create a service to handle that and use it to send any request. This service contains only one public function "send" take the data of the request and do some checks:
1- check if there is token or not: if not send request to get guest token then send the required request.
2- if there is token: check if it is expired or not: if not send the required request.
3- if expired: send refresh token request then send the required request.

my service code:

```
(function() {
  function service($http, tokenManager, apiService, API_URL, REFRESH_TOKEN_URL, appToken) {
    var s = {};
    var defaultToken = appToken;


    s.send = function(data) {
      var token = tokenManager.getToken();
      if (token && token.length > 0) {
        // check if expired
        var isTokenExpired = tokenManager.isTokenExpired();
        if (isTokenExpired) {
          sendRefreshTokenRequest(token).then(function(response) {
            // update the exist token and send with the new one
            return sendTheRequiredRequest(data, token);
          }, function(errors) {

          });
          // token is expired so we need to send refresh token then send our request
        } else {
          // send our request
          return sendTheRequiredRequest(data, token);
        }
      } else {
        token = defaultToken;
        // if the request not login or count send getToken for guest first
        if (data.loginAuthentication || data.countryCitiesAreasList) {
          //send the request with the defaultToken
          return sendTheRequiredRequest(data, defaultToken);
        } else {
          // send guest token first then the request
          sendRequestGetTokenForGuest(defaultToken).then(function(response) {
            var newToken = response.data.token;
            var isSetted = tokenManager.setToken(newToken);
            return sendTheRequiredRequest(data, newToken);
          }, function(errors) {

          });
        }
      }
    };


    function sendRequestGetTokenForGuest(token) {
      var data = apiService.getApiObj("gtoken", "11651");
      var headerParams = createHeaderParams(token);
      return $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: API_URL,
        headers: headerParams,
        data: data 
      });
    }

    function sendRefreshTokenRequest(token) {
      var headerParams = createHeaderParams(token);
      return $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: REFRESH_TOKEN_URL,
        headers: headerParams
      });
    }

    function sendTheRequiredRequest(data, token) {
      var headerParams = createHeaderParams(token);
      return $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: API_URL,
        headers: headerParams,
        data: data
      });
    }

    function createCurrentTimeStamp() {
      return Math.floor(Date.now()).toString();
    }

    function createHeaderParams(token) {
      var headerParams = {
        token: token,
        clientTimeStamp: createCurrentTimeStamp()
      };
      return headerParams;
    }

    return s;
  }
  angular.module('app').factory('apiRequestSender', service);
})();
```

I use this service in each service of each controller by calling function "send" and pass the data to it and return this:

```
return apiRequestSender.send(data);
```

then use this service in the routing like this:

```
   {
      name: 'home',
      url: '/index',
      templateUrl: 'home/views/index.html',
      controller: 'homeController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      resolve: {
        apiResponse: function(homeApiService) {
          return homeApiService.getCitiesAreas();
        }
      }
    }
```

**Now the state doesn't render so what is my wrong or how I implement these checks before each request??**

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would be useful to use an `$http` Interceptor here.
[See Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Basically, this will make sure that your function check gets executed before each
Request. The point here is that the `request` function receives a config Object, you can then
modify & check this `config` Object and all you need to do is make sure you return this (or a new) `config` Object. 
(Return directly or within a Promise)

Since you need to do some `$http` Request inside your Interceptor, you need to make sure
that it will not end up in a Infinite loop. So, the point here is to check the URL's you 
are posibly doing in the Interceptor itself, and when a Request comes with such an URL, you just 
return the Config object.

I made a Sample Factory for you with your Code

> Note that this is not tested and should just give you an Idea of how to do it

`myInterceptor.js`

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('myInterceptor', myInterceptor);


myInterceptor.$inject = [
  '$http',
  'tokenManager',
  'apiService',
  'REFRESH_TOKEN_URL',
  'GUEST_TOKEN_URL'
];

function myInterceptor($http, tokenManager, apiService, REFRESH_TOKEN_URL, GUEST_TOKEN_URL) {
  return {
    request: request
  };

  function request(config) {
    if (config.url === REFRESH_TOKEN_URL || config.url === GUEST_TOKEN_URL) {
      // Make sure to avoid an Infinite Loop (http calls within the Interceptor)
      return config;
    }

    var defaultToken = appToken;
    var token = tokenManager.getToken();
    if (token && token.length > 0) {

      var isTokenExpired = tokenManager.isTokenExpired();
      if (isTokenExpired) {

        // Set the Header Params and return the Config object.
        return sendRefreshTokenRequest(token).then(function(response) {
          config.headers = createHeaderParams(token);
          return config;
        });

      } else {

        config.headers = createHeaderParams(token);
        return config;
      }
    } else {
      token = defaultToken;

      if (data.loginAuthentication || data.countryCitiesAreasList) {
        config.headers = createHeaderParams(defaultToken);
        return config;
      } else {
        // Set the Header Params and return the Config object.
        return sendRequestGetTokenForGuest(defaultToken).then(function(response) {
          var newToken = response.data.token;
          var isSetted = tokenManager.setToken(newToken);
          config.headers = createHeaderParams(newToken);
          return config;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  function createCurrentTimeStamp() {
    return Math.floor(Date.now()).toString();
  }

  function createHeaderParams(token) {
    var headerParams = {
      token: token,
      clientTimeStamp: createCurrentTimeStamp()
    };
    return headerParams;
  }

  function sendRequestGetTokenForGuest(token) {
    var data = apiService.getApiObj("gtoken", "11651");
    var headerParams = createHeaderParams(token);
    return $http({
      method: "POST",
      // url: API_URL,
      // Changed because you want to capture this URL in the Interceptor,
      // so it wont do its checks when the url is like this. (avoid Infinite loop)
      url: GUEST_TOKEN_URL,
      headers: headerParams,
      data: data
    });
  }

  function sendRefreshTokenRequest(token) {
    var headerParams = createHeaderParams(token);
    return $http({
      method: "POST",
      url: REFRESH_TOKEN_URL,
      headers: headerParams
    });
  }
}
```

Register the Interceptor:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
 }]);
```

Hope this is helpful :)